# Using Inverse Laplace Transform to solve a differential equation involving F(s), F(s+a),F(s-a) and others .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, special-functions, laplace-transform, hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to get the inverse Laplace transform of the following expression:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  2 F(s)=\frac{-\alpha ^2 A}{\left(-B -\alpha ^2 A -s^{2}\right)}F(s+2 \alpha )+\frac{-\alpha ^2 A}{\left(-B -\alpha ^2 A -s^{2}\right)} F(s-2 \alpha)\\
  +\frac{-\left((s+4\alpha)^2+B\right)}{\left(-B -\alpha ^2 A -s^{2}\right)}F(s+4 \alpha )+\frac{-\left((s-4\alpha)^2+B\right)}{\left(-B -\alpha ^2 A -s^{2}\right)}F(s-4 \alpha )
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

being $A,B,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

It seems to me that the Inverse laplace transform of this expression does not exist,  the terms $F(s),F(s-4 \alpha ),F(s+4 \alpha )$, etc, seems to cancel each other by the Shifting Theorem of the Laplace transform:

$\displaystyle{ \mathcal{L}\{ e^{-at} f(t) \} = F(s+a) }$

And at the end we get some kind of expression like

$0=0$

It seems to me that  I am doing something wrong, since the Inverse Laplace transform seems to cancel itself. Do you have any ideas on how could I try to get the inverse transform to get $f(t)$?

A hint I suspect, it **could** be somehow related to the Hypergeometric differential equation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $F(s+2\alpha)+F(s-2\alpha) = 2L[f(t)\cosh(2\alpha)]$

Comment: There is not cancellation.

Comment: How? I tried but at the end I get a bunch of things like: $2 F(s)= P_1(s) 2L[f(t)\cosh(2\alpha)]+P_2(s) 2L[f(t)\cosh(4\alpha)]-P_3(s) F(s+4\alpha)+P_3(s) F(s-4\alpha)$   , Let $P_n(s)$ be rational expressions.